# URL Decode (for Extended Ascii) using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, url-encoding, string-decoding

I am needing some help fine tuning a T-SQL function to properly DECODE a string which contains URL. Just the query string parameter **values** are URLEcoded (and not the whole URL). The original function works well when decoding **single byte characters** however it doesn't handle **multiple byte characters**. In order to address the DECODING of multiple byte characters such as Spanish Accented characters; my plan was to find the values using PATINDEX and replace those using a lookup table (this is because we are dealing with a small finite number of specials characters which fall in this category).

**Problem:**
The Pattern specified below is not returning any matches therefore I am pretty much stuck at this point.

**Example:**
Pattern '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%' works for single byte encoded chars. Similarly Pattern '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%' **should work** for double byte chars such as (%C3%A9 -> ) **but it does not.**

Here is my code:

```
 DECLARE @Position INT,
    @Base CHAR(16),
    @High TINYINT,
    @Low TINYINT,
    @Pattern VARCHAR(256),
    @URL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Url = '%26Text1%3DFrom%20Ren%C3%A9%27s'

SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
    @Pattern = '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%',
    --@URL = REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' '),
    @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

PRINT 'Position: ' + + CAST(@Position AS Varchar(256))

WHILE @Position > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT  
        @High = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 1, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @Low = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 2, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @URL = STUFF(@URL, @Position, 6, '123456'),
        @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

    PRINT 'High: ' + CAST(@High AS Varchar(256))

    PRINT @URL
END
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean 4 sets from double byte?  Cleary %C3%A9 is just two sets.

Comment: Pattern should match 2 sets of double byte chars. Here is my understanding: [%] matches the literal (i.e. '%') preceding 'C3'. [0-9a-f] matches a single AlphaNumeric charecter (i.e. 'C'). The repeated [0-9a-f] matches the second single AlphaNumeric character (i.e. 3) so [%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f] should match '%C3' and similarlyl the second set of pattern **should** match '%A9'. What am I missing?

Comment: OK but is %C3%A9 two sets of double bytes or one?

Comment: **%C3%A9** is a set of double bytes each encoded separately. In other words **%C3** alone equates to **Ã** and **%A9** alone equates to **©** but combined they should spit out **é**

Comment: "Similarly Pattern '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%' should work for double byte chars such as (%C3%A9 -> ) but it does not."  That pattern is two double bytes and %C3%A9 is one.

Comment: @Blam, I am not understanding how the pattern is flawed ... can you give me an example of how the pattern is not fashioned correctly? See my explanation / understanding of the pattern, above.

Comment: Let's count. The pattern has 4 (hard) % and %C3%A9 has 2.  4 != 2

Comment: @Blam, the leading and trailing '%' are the wild-cards.

Comment: Count the %.  The pattern has 4 [%] in addition to the staring and ending.  The search string has only two % - %C3%A9.

Comment: @Blam, see my answer below. It has the correct pattern ... what you are referring to (pattern listed within the comment above) was a typo. Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score -1):

@Pattern CHAR(21) is truncating

see

```
set nocount on
 DECLARE @Position INT,
    @Base CHAR(16),
    @High TINYINT,
    @Low TINYINT,
    @Pattern VARCHAR(200),
    @URL VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Url = '%26Text1%3DFrom%20Ren%C3%A9%27s'

SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
    @Pattern = '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%',
    --@URL = REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' '),
    @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

select @URL
select @Pattern    
select @position
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to 256 (just to be safe) but doesnt change the behavior ... meaning still no match.

Comment: You are consistent in your lack of attention to detail. varchar not char.

Answer (score -1):

I had a syntax error within the pattern. After reading the documentation closely I realized that I needed to escape % sign using an additional percent sign. Here is the working solution (the sub query to replace the value is not working but the pattern is):

```
    DECLARE @Position INT,
    @Base CHAR(16),
    @High TINYINT,
    @Low TINYINT,
    @Pattern nVARCHAR(256),
    @ToReplace nVARCHAR(256),
    @ReplaceWith nVARCHAR(256),
    @URL nVARCHAR(4000)

SET @Url = '%26Text1%3DFrom%20Ren%C3%A9%27s%C3'

SELECT  @Base = '0123456789abcdef',
    @Pattern = '%[%%][c-f][0-9]%%[0-9a-f]%',
    --@URL = REPLACE(@URL, '+', ' '),
    @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

  PRINT 'Position: ' + + CAST(@Position AS Varchar(256))

WHILE @Position > 0
  BEGIN
  SELECT  
        @High = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 1, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @Low = CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position + 2, 1), @Base COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS),
        @ToReplace = SUBSTRING(@URL, @Position, 6),
        @ReplaceWith = (SELECT COALESCE([Text], 'Something') FROM dbo.ExtendedAsciiLookup WHERE UTF = @ToReplace),
        @URL = STUFF(@URL, @Position, 6, @ReplaceWith),
        @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @URL)

        PRINT 'High: ' + CAST(@High AS Varchar(256))
        PRINT '@ToReplace: ' + CAST(COALESCE(@ToReplace,'') AS nVARCHAR(256))
        PRINT 'With: ' + CAST(COALESCE(@ReplaceWith,'') AS VARCHAR(256))

        PRINT @URL
END
```